# Filtering keywords from a master list

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have a master list (A) containing keywords that cannot be contained in List B. I need to find any words in a column in List B that are contained in master list (A) and show them in another column. I think it may be a double array formula, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Select the first cell in the column with ListB, Home > Styles > Conditional Formatting, New Rule, Use a formula to determine which cells to format, under Format values where this formula is true enter `=MATCH(B1,A:A)`, click and select a format (such as yellow highlight) and ensure Applies to is `=$B:$B`. Then filter ListB selecting yellow, copy and paste to new column and remove filter.